# How to split varnishncsa logs into separate under systemd (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: systemd, varnish

I need to have `varnishncsa` split logs to separate files based on vhost.

I know I can make an override configuration in `/etc/systemd/system/varnishncsa.service.d` that will filter on a specific vhost.

Something like this somedomain.conf:

```
[Service]
RuntimeDirectory=varnishncsa
Type=forking
User=varnishlog
Group=varnish
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: somedomain.com'" -D -a -w /var/log/varnish/somedomain.log -P /run/varnishncsa/varnishncsa.pid -F '%%{X-Forwarded-For}i %%l %%u %%t "%%r" %%s %%b "%%{Referer}i" "%%{User-agent}i"'
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateNetwork=true
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full
PIDFile=/run/varnishncsa/varnishncsa.pid
```

But how can i make it generate a separate log file for each of many vhosts?

I want to feed these per domain logs into awstats.

Comment: But are you sure that you want to really do this in the first place? The `Host` client header can easily be forget to a host that does not even exist. You might end up with dozens or hundreds of log files.

Comment: https://varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2016-November/025399.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods I've seen leave you 2 options. 1 is to log everything to a single file and then use varnishlog to parse the log to see just the vhost that you're interested in. More on this tool is here - https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishlog.html.

To split the logs into explicit files you have to run multiple `varnishncsa` daemons. The method is shown in this blog titled: [How to split Varnish log for Virtual host](https://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-split-varnish-log-for-virtual-host).

For example:

*varnish 3.x*

```
varnishncsa -m "RxHeader:^Host: linuxaria.com$" -a -w /var/log/varnish/linuxaria.com.access_log -D
varnishncsa -m "RxHeader:^Host: linuxaria.org$" -a -w /var/log/varnish/linuxaria.org.access_log -D
```

*varnish 4.x*

```
varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: .*\.example1.com'"
varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: .*\.example2.com'"
```

You'd need to set this up as individualized systemd unit files, one per vhost. **NOTE:** The method is also discussed in this blog post titled: [[tips]varnishncsa save the split log for every host](http://blog.xcir.net/?p=990).

#### Your example

So for each unit file, 1 per vhost, you'd add your exec line like so:

*unit file #1*

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: somedomain1.com'" -D -a -w /var/log/varnish/somedomain1.log -P /run/varnishncsa/varnishncsa_vhost1.pid -F '%%{X-Forwarded-For}i %%l %%u %%t "%%r" %%s %%b "%%{Referer}i" "%%{User-agent}i"'
```

*unit file #2*

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/varnishncsa -q "ReqHeader ~ '^Host: somedomain2.com'" -D -a -w /var/log/varnish/somedomain2.log -P /run/varnishncsa/varnishncsa_vhost2.pid -F '%%{X-Forwarded-For}i %%l %%u %%t "%%r" %%s %%b "%%{Referer}i" "%%{User-agent}i"'
```